# ggplot2 bubbleplot with clustering data

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, bubble-chart

I can do a bubble plot using ggplot2. now I want to clustering one column then do the bubble plot.  how can I do that?
Here is what the plot look like:
the image look like  this one

[image: plot]

Here is my dummy data

```
x=data.frame(
group=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D"),
item=c("apple","pear","apple","peach","orange","cherry","apple","banna","apple"),
count=c(3,5,5,1,9,7,3,2,4))
```

Here are my scripts:

```
library(ggplot2)

xf=x$item
xfu=unique(xf)
x$item=factor(xf,levels=xfu)
p<-ggplot(x)
p + geom_point(aes(x = group, y = item,size= count),las=2,shape=16,
alpha=0.80) +
scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 
1.1,size=11,colour="black",face="bold"),
axis.text.y = element_text(size=11,colour="black"),
axis.title.y = element_text(size=12,colour =
"black",face="bold",vjust=0.12))+
labs(x="",y = "Item")
```

Now I want to do a hierarchical clustering on the item data so as to get a more apparent pattern about it. The order of item is not important. How can I do that?

Comment: The image link doesn't help much, if you could be more specific about what exactly your chart should look like for your data.frame then it would be much easier for people to answer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited on http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I think it belongs here because she needs to recode the factor levels to make them plot in the right order - not a stat Q. what order is desired is less clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how you scale up the bubbles to overlap, you need to explicitly set `size=` *outside* the `aes()` parameter (as below). I've added the labels with a `geom_text()` call.

If you want the columns to cluster together based on some order, though, you need a continuous variable to plot against (need more info to demonstrate)

```
xf=x$item
xfu=unique(xf)
x$item=factor(xf,levels=xfu)
p<-ggplot(x)
p + geom_point(aes(x = group, y = item), size=15+x$count*7, las=2,shape=21, fill="white", alpha=0.80) +
geom_text(aes(x = group, y = item, label=count), fontface="bold", size=7) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 
                                     1.1,size=11,colour="black",face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=11,colour="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=12,colour =
                                      "black",face="bold",vjust=0.12),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(linetype = "dashed", size=1, color="black"))+
  labs(x="",y = "Item")
```

[image]